# Swift: find out how many digits an integer has

Tags: swift

I don't have the right English or math vocabulary to really explain what I want to do, but I'll try to explain. Basically I want to figure out "how big" an integer is, how many decimal positions it has. For example 1234 is "a thousand" number, and 2,987,123 is "a million" number.

I can do something like this, but that is rather silly :)

```
extension Int {
  func size() -> Int {
    switch self {
    case 0...99:
      return 10

    case 100...999:
      return 100

    case 1000...9999:
      return 1000

    case 10000...99999:
      return 10000

    case 100000...999999:
      return 100000

    case 1000000...9999999:
      return 1000000

    default:
      return 0 // where do we stop?
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A solution using logarithms:**

> **Note:** This solution has limitations due to the inability of `Double` to fully represent the `log10` of large `Int` converted to `Double`.  It starts failing around 15
> digits for `Int`s very close to the next power of 10 (e.g.
> `999999999999999`).
>
> This is a problem:
>
> ```
>  log10(Double(999999999999999)) == log10(Double(1000000000000000))
> ```

```
extension Int {
    var size: Int {
        self == 0 ? 1 : Int(pow(10.0, floor(log10(abs(Double(self))))))
    }
}
```

---

**A solution using Strings:**

It avoids any mathematical representation errors by working entirely with `Int` and `String`.

```
extension Int {
    var size: Int {
        Int("1" + repeatElement("0", count: String(self.magnitude).count - 1))!
    }
}
```

---

**A generic version for any `FixedWidthInteger`:**

In collaboration with @LeoDabus, I present the *generic* version for any integer type:

```
extension FixedWidthInteger {
    var size: Self {
        Self("1" + repeatElement("0", count: String(self.magnitude).count - 1))!
    }
}
```

**Examples:**

```
Int8.max.size     // 100
Int16.max.size    // 10000
Int32.max.size    // 1000000000
Int.max.size      // 1000000000000000000
UInt.max.size     // 10000000000000000000
```

Comment: Thanks! My (embarrassing) math skills really let me down here to come up with something like this myself haha.

Comment: The log one crashes for negative Ints.  What would you like as an answer in that case?  `(-1234).size` should give what?

Comment: I'll change both to take the `abs()` of the `Int` first.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not `log10` and avoid division instead?

Comment: @Alladinian, only because I missed seeing `log10` when I was looking through the `log` variants.  Thanks.

Comment: @vacawama generic version `extension FixedWidthInteger where Self: Comparable & SignedNumeric {` `var double: Double { .init(self) }` `var abs: Self { Swift.abs(self) }` `var size: Self {` `self == 0 ? 1 : Self(pow(10.0, log10(abs.double).rounded(.down)))` `}` `}`

Comment: I would recommend coming up with a better name than `size`. For one, it's not clear how it's different from the existing `.magnitude`, and worse yet, it's entirely unclear that you're talking about the number of digits. Why isn't it the number of bits, for example? I would suggest `decimalRepresentationLength`.

Comment: Thanks, @LeoDabus.  That looks great.  I'm still testing my answer and seeing issues with the log version ...

Comment: @vacawama it actually lacks support to unsigned integer

Comment: @vacawama To support unsigned integers as well we can use magnitude property instead of abs `extension FixedWidthInteger {`  `var double: Double { .init(self) }` `var size: Self {` `self == 0 ? 1 : Self(pow(10.0, log10(magnitude.double).rounded(.down)))` `}` `}`

Comment: @LeoDabus, since the `log10` solution is fundamentally flawed due to limitations in `Double`, I think a generic solution should be based upon the `String` version.

Comment: I agree but in most cases we don't need such a high value

Comment: @vacawama the generic string version `extension FixedWidthInteger {` `var size: Int {` `Int("1" + repeatElement("0", count: String(magnitude).count-1))!` `}` `}`

Comment: `UInt.max.size` crashes.  We either need to return `UInt` or `Self` for the generic.

Comment: `extension FixedWidthInteger {` `var size: Self {` `Self("1" + repeatElement("0", count: String(magnitude).string.count-1))!` `}` `}`

Comment: @LeoDabus, I added the generic answer.  This certainly turned out to be a more challenging problem than I'd first anticipated.

Comment: @vacawama there is a left over in my comment above that was not properly edited. When I  added the string initializer I forgot to remove the string property `String(magnitude).count`. I was using this extension `extension LosslessStringConvertible {` `var string: String { .init(self) }` `}`

Comment: @LeoDabus, I was working off of your prior comment so I didn't even see that leftover.

Comment: Thank you all for your input! The final generic answer looks great, and yeah a more complex problem than I also anticipated. Too bad the question got (some) downvote(s), but oh well :)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```swift
extension Int {
  func size() -> Int {
    var size = 1
    var modifyingNumber = self

    while modifyingNumber > 10 {
      modifyingNumber = modifyingNumber / 10
      size = size * 10
    }

    return size
  }
}
```

Works, but it's rather imperative.

Comment: This repeated division by a number to calculate how many times it can be divided is called a ["logarithm"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) in math. It's the inverse of exponentiation. E.g. if `10^5 = 10_1000`, then `log_10(10_000) = 5`

Comment: Thanks! It's been way too long since I learned this stuff and honestly never needed it anymore in the past 20 years haha. I've forgotten it all 

Comment: Perhaps there were times when it would have been useful, but you wouldn't have known because you didn't know what you didn't know :p

Comment: I consider it more helpful to encourage users for providing working solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Is this too silly?

```
extension Int {
    var size : Int {
        String(self).count
    }
}
```

My reasoning is that a "digit" really *is* a manner of writing, so converting to String answers the real question. Converting the size back to a *number* (i.e. the corresponding power of ten) would then of course lead right back to the logarithm answer. :)

Comment: Well, I said it was silly. :) I just counted digits; 11000 does have 5 digits. The OP said we are always positive so I took that as gospel; originally I had a `filter` for numeric characters but I took it out because of that.

Comment: OP wants `12345.size` to return `10000`, not `5`.

Comment: @vacawama I know, that's why I said we lead back to your answer. No one seems to be getting into the spirit here. _I said it was silly._ Sheesh.

Comment: I don't think this is silly.  I too had provided a String based solution from the start and as it turns out, the `log` version is flawed due to the limitations of `Double`.